# Restore DB data after XAMPP uninstallation

Tags: mysql, database, xampp

I uninstalled XAMPP from my pc, during the uninstallation the system asked me if wanted to delete htdocs folder (I selected "yes" because I made a backup of this folder before the uninstallation), after that the system asked me if I wanted to delete Mysql data and I selected "NO".

After the uninstallation I had still some folder in C:/xampp (also mysql folder).

Now I reinstalled XAMPP but is there a method to restore DB file with the folders that I have?

I tried to replace the mysql folder but it wasn't a good idea.

This is a screenshot of the folders that are remained after the uninstallation:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The databases are stored on xampp\mysql\data location on this location you find the folder for each database in this folder you have file db.opt and also two file for each table that is (yourtableName.frm and yourtableName.ibd) 
something like....

[image]

if you put that all dbfolder (in mycase i.e. "empdb") in to above location you will get your database back to used

Hope it make sense